# Using html object tag to embed HTML works, but IE7 has scrollbars

Tags: css, xhtml, object, internet-explorer-7

```
<object id="page" type="text/html" 
data="index_test.html" 
width="565" height="500"> 
  <p>Oops! That didn't work...</p> 
</object>
```

This is what I have and works in Firefox, but IE7 has scrollbars. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As much as it pains me to recommend it, render scroll="no" on the <body> tag. This will eliminate the default scrollbars in IE7. IE8 and other standard browsers can mark overflow:auto on the CSS for the body tag without needing scroll="no"

To clarify, add scroll="no" on the body tag in your index_test.html

Comment: <object id="page" type="text/html" scroll="no"   

?

Comment: No, in the content of index_test.html, make sure your body tag looks like <body scroll="no"> The problem is coming from the child page, not the page that contains the <object> tag.

Comment: Thank You.

Another issue is that in ie7 there is a bounding box, a kind of drop shadow, encompassing the dimensions of the object 

Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: I think you were avoiding iframe, but I cannot find how you can eliminate the frame border using the object tag. You could instead use iframe with the frameborder attribute:
<iframe src="index_test.html" width="565" height="500" frameborder="no"></iframe>